# Angle between arbitrary rectangle and horizontal plane

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry, euclidean-domain

This seems to me like a fairly simple problem but I'm constantly re-thinking it because something seems wrong about how I'm solving it. I feel like there may be perhaps an easier solution or something I missed which would invalidate mine

The problem is:
Say we have a arbitrary rectangle in an euclidean 2D plane for whose 4 vertices we know the coordinates. The angle for this rectangle is measured always as the angle between a horizontal plane (x-axis, which it is always above) and the side which would be parallel to the horizontal plane first if the rectangle were to be rotated counter-clockwise. We have to instead figure out the absolute value of the angle of the offset between the bottom line of the rectangle and the beginning of the unit circle. We're always given the angle between the side that would touch be parallel to the horizontal line if the rectangle was rotated counter-clockwise, as explained above.

We need to figure out this angle for any arbitrary rectangle. And to clarify this is in code, so eyeballing it and using tools is out of the question.

Currently I'm solving it very simply by taking the x coordinate of the bottom-most point. and checking it against the x coordinates of the left-most and right-most point. Based on which one is closer, the answer is either just simply the given angle, or 90 subtracted by the given angle.

I am not sure if this solution works globally and I'm not sure how to prove it, or if there's a better one.

[image: Example]

In the example above, Alpha is always given (the angle between the side that would be parallel to x-axis first if rotated counter-clockwise), and Beta is the required solution. In the left example, we need to subtract Alpha from 90 to get the solution, in the right example, alpha is already equal to the correct solution.

Comment: You don't need the rightmost point. The left point from the bottom-most point is the one which forms the angle you require. As you are always going to rotate anticlockwise, it is the leftmost point which will reach the horizontal first. So the angle you want is the one made by the line from the bottom to the left point with the horizontal -- in all cases. Unless one side is already horizontal of course. So that means $\alpha$ in both of the above cases. And in your diagram on the right, both angles are $\alpha$.

Comment: The problem is that α is always given. The angle I need is Beta in both of the above example cases. I understand the α = Beta in the second example, but that was the point of the example, to show that here α is the correct answer. To clarify the example on the left, let's assume α = 40 degrees. In this case, the correct answer is 50 degrees, as in the angle between the x-axis and the right-most point. In the example on the right however, the correct answer is α itself, which is equal to B. In otherwords, we always need the angle in the I. or IV. quadrant around the point touching the x axis

Comment: @JackAvante Oh okay, sorry, I misunderstood. But then I still don't understand. What do you mean by "the beginning of the unit circle". I can't work out what it actually is that you want to work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are using may not always work.

Consider points $(x_n, y_n), 1 \leq n \leq 4$ anti-clockwise. Say $(x_1, y_1)$ is the vertex with least $y$ value. Now there will be two adjacent sides that contain this vertex - one is the length of the rectangle and the other is the width (length > width). If you always want to find the absolute angle of the side which is length, with the horizontal axis, your method may not work when, for example, the rectangle is almost vertical [note $x_4$ is min($x$) and $x_2$ is max ($x$)]. You may have $|x_2 - x_1| \leq |x_4 - x_1|$ but the angle you want is $(90^0 - \alpha)$ and not $\alpha$.

Here is what I suggest -

First find vertex with min($y$), say it is $(x_i, y_i)$. Now find vertices which has min ($x$) and max ($x$) of the remaining *three* vertices. Say they are $(x_j, y_j)$ and $(x_k, y_k)$ respectively.

You are already given absolute angle of line segment from $(x_i, y_i)$ to $(x_j, y_j)$, with the horizontal axis.

Next find $d_{ij} = \sqrt{(x_j - x_i)^2 + (y_j - y_i)^2}$ and $d_{ik} = \sqrt{(x_k - x_i)^2 + (y_k - y_i)^2}$. If $|d_{ij}| \gt |d_{ik}|$, the angle you want is the given angle $\alpha$. If $|d_{ij}| \lt |d_{ik}|$, the angle you want is $(90^0 - \alpha)$. If $|d_{ij}| = |d_{ik}|, $ you do not have a rectangle (instead it is a square).